# Filtereing elements with css rules - how to increase specifity

Tags: css, filter

**Premise**

I'm having a container with elements of the type `<div class="event-item">` (n > 500) where each has the attributes **a**, **b** and **c** and values of a1, a2, ... b1, b2, etc. E.g.

```
<div class="event-item" data-a="1" data-b="1" data-c="2">
<div class="event-item" data-a="2" data-b="7" data-c="2">
<div class="event-item" data-a="1" data-b="5" data-c="2">
<div class="event-item" data-a="4" data-b="2" data-c="1">
<div class="event-item" data-a="8" data-b="3" data-c="1">
```

Now, I'm implementing filters in the UI, so that the user can dynamically hide elements that do not match the rules. The UI looks like this:

[image: Filters in action]

E.g. if value 3 and 5 of filter B are enabled, only items matching these two values are displayed. Clicking on "Reset filter..." will disable this filter, unchecking value 3 and 5. The filters' logical combination should be **AND**, meaning if filter A value 1 is active and filter B value 3 is active, elements have to apply **BOTH** conditions to be displayed. Otherwise they're hidden.

**This is how I did it and why this is a problem**

Say, in case the value 3 of filter A gets checked I add the class ".filtered-a" to the container of the event items. Simultaneously, I add the class ".preserved-a" to all event items that have data-a="3". The according css is:

```
#eventlist.filtered-a .event-item{display:none;}
#eventlist.filtered-a .event-item.preserved-a{display:inline-block;}
```

Accordingly, I extended the css for the filter B and C. It works like a charm when one filter is used. But, when more than one filter is active, the event-item has to only match one filter rule in order to be displayed, making the logical combination an **OR**.

**What I tried**

I tried a css solution with multiple class combinations:

```
#eventlist.filtered-a .event-item,
#eventlist.filtered-b .event-item,
#eventlist.filtered-c .event-item,
#eventlist.filtered-a.filtered-b .event-item,
#eventlist.filtered-a.filtered-c .event-item,
#eventlist.filtered-b.filtered-c .event-item,
#eventlist.filtered-a.filtered-b.filtered-c .event-item{display:none;}

#eventlist.filtered-a .event-item.preserved-a,
#eventlist.filtered-b .event-item.preserved-b,
#eventlist.filtered-c .event-item.preserved-c,
#eventlist.filtered-a.filtered-b .event-item.preserved-a.preserved-b,
#eventlist.filtered-a.filtered-c .event-item.preserved-a.preserved-c,
#eventlist.filtered-b.filtered-c .event-item.preserved-b.preserved-c,
#eventlist.filtered-a.filtered-b.filtered-c .event-item.preserved-a.preserved-b.preserved-c{display:inline-block;}
```

... hoping the multiple classes on the parent element would increase the css specifity, which is not the case. Also, this solution is very ugly and the css will be a nightmare if a fourth parameter would be implemented.

This is my jquery that does the filtering (exemplary only filter a)

```
$("#eventlist").removeClass("filtered-a");
$("#eventlist .event-item").removeClass("preserved-a");

$(".eventlist-filter-a input").each(function(){
  if($(this).is(":checked")){
    $("#eventlist").addClass("filtered-a");
    $("#eventlist .event-item."+$(this).val()).addClass("preserved-a");
  } 
});
```

I have to preserve elements that match the filter, instead of hide elements that doesn't because of the way I iterate over the input elements of the filter list with $().each().

**Question**

How can I effectively implement a filter functionality, based on css classes.

Comment: To the container? Well, that doesn't allow for an easy css solution, either, does it? Imagine, the container has class ".enabled" and there is an element with class ".preserve-a", one with "preserve-a preserve-b" and one with "preserve-b". I want only the second element to be displayed then.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

I found a solution inverting the machanisms by actively hide filtered elements.
The jquery:

```
// reset filters
$("#eventlist *").removeClass("filtered-a filtered-b filtered-c");

// apply filters
if(filter = $(".eventlist-filter-a input:checked").map(function(){ return "." + $(this).val(); }).get().join()){    
  $("#eventlist .event-item").not(filter).addClass("filtered-a");
}
```

Explanation: the function get the value of all checked checkboxes and creates a jquery selector from it. The selector is inverted (here not()) and all matching elements get the class "filtered". This can be done for all three filters and everybody is happy ;)

The css reduces to:

```
#eventlist .event-item{display:inline-block; font-size:13px;line-height:20px;}
#eventlist .event-item.filtered-a{display:none}
```